# No results when query for old records in Cassandra after bulk restore using SSTableloader

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am having a very weird situation.
I was having a 3 node cluster each having arrund 300GB data.
I had to move the cluster to new 5 node cluster. 
I used sstableLoader to move the data.
Once sstableloader is completed successfully I can query for the restored records over cqlsh.
But I can not query for those restored records from java code.
Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add java code & other details, for example, do you get any error in java code? If data is visible in cqlsh, they are accessible from anywhere... I can only think about permission problems...

Comment: What kind of permission problems it could be? because with 3 node cluster the same java code was working fine.

Comment: I meant permissions to tables if use authentication/authorization... but add more information to your question - it’s hard to say anything about it